# how can I discover device name through probe requests?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I am scripting a scapy probe request scanner using python 2.x. I can scan for probes and list the mac address, manufacturer and ssid being probed for.
How can I now discover the device name for these devices (ex: Gio's iPhone 5)?? I am aware that this cannot be done through probe requests alone. But what kind of connection and packet will I have to send the device for it to divulge its device name?

this is the script in question if anyone is interested: https://github.com/localtracker/pyrobe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device name won't be given up until it does a DHCP request and passes up its name.  You could try to put up a SSID that the device will connect to (since you know what it's probing for) and then wait for the DHCP packet to come in after it associates.  This will only work if you use an SSID that the device doesn't think there are security requirements for, so its best to try public ones like Starbucks, Mcdonalds, etc.